# Doing calculation from user's input

Tags: python, input

Please what code can I use to achieve something like this in python:

I want to first get user input where the user will enter the operator and two operands then use the operator to calculate both operands to give the answer.

A sample execution of code is:

```
Please enter your calculations in this order: + 3 3
Your answer is 6
```

Comment: HINT: a,b,c = input().rsplit(),

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always try to show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can use this simple script to understand the operations

operand = input('enetr the + , - , * , / please:  ')
num1 , num2 = input('enetr first and second number please: ').split() #note : enetr 
#the first number then space and second number 

num1 =  int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)

if operand ==  '+':
print('your answer is ',num1 + num2)
if operand == '-':
print('your answer is ',num1 - num2)
if operand == '/':
print('your answer is ',num1 / num2)
if operand == '*':
print('your answer is ',num1 * num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take two operands as a integers and and use if statement or switch to check operator and based on that operator perform operation like if operator was '+' and was found to be true in statement then add those operands `:)` and so on for others, too...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want a single input of the form "(operand) (first number) (second number)". In that case, first, you will want to use a split function, as suggested by Arun K. Then you will want to convert the numbers from string to integer, and then compare the operator with a preset list of operators. The code should probably look something like this:

```
problem = input("Enter 2 operands and operator divided by space (e.g. 3 3 +): ")
a,b,operator = problem.split(" ")
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
if operator == "+":
  c = a+b
elif operator == "*":
  c = a*b
# more operators here, if required
print('Result: {}'.format(c))
```

If you really want to be thorough then you can make sure that the input is correct by using try/except statements.